# Ubercart- free shipping through pay per click

Tags: ubercart

Can anyone think of a way to offer free shipping for people who arrive at the site through Pay-per-click advertising (without a coupon code).

drupal 7.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Commerce Free Shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_free_shipping) module.

> This module provide a solution to add Free shipping rate on top of
>   commerce_shipping services.
>
> This module change the price of the service to 0 and can display a
>   message to the user saying the free shipping are applyed or the amount
>   left to obtain free shipping.
>
> You can use this module to have a free shipping rate by:
>
> - Shipping service
> - Total amount of the line items in the cart (don't take in account the shipping line items)

[How to setup free shipping](https://www.drupal.org/node/1326736)